# Strings not formatted in Node.js after a non-string

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is the following a bug or a feature in Node.js? If it is a feature, please point out at the spec.

When we call this:

```
console.log('one\ntwo', 'three\nfour');
```

we get the expected:

```
one
two three
four
```

But if we use a non-string value in front of it, then strings are no longer formatted as expected:

```
console.log(1, 'one\ntwo', 'three\nfour');
```

outputs:

```
1 'one\ntwo' 'three\nfour'
```

Why is that?

**UPDATE**

From [the link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) by @MuliYulzary, it would appear that it is supposed to set the formatting, based on whether the first parameter is a string or not.

I found out, that when the first parameter is a string, Node.js uses `util.format(parameters)`, and when the first parameter is not a string, it uses `util.inspect`.

That's how it works.

Comment: Have a look at this. basically you're running another variant of console.log with different purpose. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log

Comment: There is no spec for `console.log`.

Comment: @Bergi of course there is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log

Comment: @vitaly-t: That's the MDN documentation covering Firefox' inbuilt console, not a spec. Or do you refer to the https://github.com/DeveloperToolsWG/console-object/blob/master/api.md#consolelogobject--object- linked from MDN?

Answer (score 0):

From the document [console.log](https://github.com/DeveloperToolsWG/console-object/blob/master/api.md#consolelogobject--object-), it works correctly

```
console.log(object [, object, ...])

Logs a debug level message. You pass one or more objects to this method, each of which are evaluated and concatenated into a space-delimited string. The first parameter you pass to console.log() may contain Format Specifiers.
```

See the sample usage [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Outputting_text_to_the_console)